# Php type hinting not getting along with interfaces and abstract classes?

Tags: php, interface, types, abstract-class

I think it'll be much easier to see the problem in a code example than writing the question in the first place. Here is my php code:

```
<?php

interface AnInterface
{
        public function method();
}    

class AClass implements AnInterface
{
        public function method()
        {
                echo __METHOD__;
        }
}    

abstract class AnAbstractClass
{
        abstract public function method( AnInterface $Object );
}

class ConcreteClass extends AnAbstractClass
{
        public function method( AClass $Object )
        {
                $Object->method();
        }
}

$Object1 = new ConcreteClass();
$Object2 = new AClass();

$Object1->method( $Object2 );
```

The above code causes the following error:

> Fatal error: Declaration of ConcreteClass::method() must be compatible with that of AnAbstractClass::method()

The problem is that php doesn't seem to be recognizing the signatures of AnAbstractClass::method and ConcreteClass::method as compatible. Am I doing something wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please, *please* get into the habit of posting the error message your code is generating. Posting code without posting the output (or error) is useless.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> php doesn't seem to be recognizing the signatures of `AnAbstractClass::method` and `ConcreteClass::method` as compatible.

PHP is correct, they're **not** compatible. By allowing only instances of `AClass` (or its children) to be passed to `ConcreteClass::method`, you're breaking the contract that `AnAbstractClass`  provides: Any of its subclasses must accept `AnInterface` as an argument to its `method()`.

If your example worked, and I had another class `BClass` implementing `AnInterface`, we'd have a situation where according to `AnAbstractClass`, `method()` should accept instances of `BClass`, while according to `ConcreteClass`, it shouldn't.

Change your signature for `ConcreteClass::method` to match that of `AnAbstractClass::method`.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example that shows, why this is not allowed:

```
<?php
class BClass implements AnInterface { }

function moo(AnAbstractClass $abstract)
{
    $b = new BClass();
    $abstract->method($b);
}
```

This would be a valid code, but it would fail, if you pass a `ConcreteClass` to moo, because its method `ConcreteClass::method` does not allow `BClass`.

It is complicated, but it is easier to understand, if you see an example.

Answer (score 2):

Does not compute. We had the same discussion yesterday:
[Can parameter types be specialized in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553943/can-parameter-types-be-specialized-in-php/4554120#4554120)

All your derived classes must implement the method signatures identically.

This is something that would ideally be checked at runtime. But in PHP the parser does. (To compensate, PHP does not check private/protected attribute access at parsing time, but let that one rather blow up at runtime.)

If you want to enforce a more stringent type, I would advise:

```
 assert( is_a($Object, "AClass") );
```

Comment: Given that it's PHP 5, that assertion should read `assert($Object instanceof AClass);`

Comment: Yes, that might work, but actually it's not the way it is supposed to be, I think I had a misconception in the first place, see the answer from @meagar

Comment: Cases like inheriting from ArrayObject would ISTM be good candidates for doing a type assertion or throwing if the wrong type were received. But you can't change the basic interface (e.g. ArrayAccess::offsetSet is always going to take a mixed parameter for the value).