# Override interface parent method that use type hinting

Tags: php, interface, type-hinting

Let's say my boss have a class and interface:

```
class HisBar {}

interface HisFooInterface
{
    public function doSomethingWithBar(HisBar $bar);
}
```

and I have my own class that may or may not extends `HisBar`

```
class MyBar extends HisBar {}
```

I wish I could do this :

```
interface MyFooInterface extends HisFooInterface
{
    public function doSomethingWithBar(MyBar $bar);
}
```

But, Yes, I get the error :

> **Fatal error**: Declaration of MyFooInterface::doSomethingWithBar() must
>   be compatible with HisFooInterface::doSomethingWithBar(HisBar $bar) in
>   path\to\MyFooInterface.php on line xx

I mean, I need use an instance of the interface but with different type hinting, is that even possible ? Is there any way to do this ? How to change type of the argument ? Thanks.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567020/php-type-hinting-not-getting-along-with-interfaces-and-abstract-classes

Comment: No - you're changing the method by making it more explicit, which breaks `HisFooInterface`'s contract. In theory, you could just accept `stdClass` or use no type hint at all, but that defeats the purpose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override method parameter with child interface as a new parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19429089/override-method-parameter-with-child-interface-as-a-new-parameter)

Comment: @GeorgeBrighton bytheway, I did it with `no type hint at all` but still same. So, there is nothing I can do with that kind of interface? type hint makes the interface to be inflexible/ unchangeable ?

Comment: If you redefine accepted types in a child interface, you're breaking what you declared in the parent interface. It's simply a logical problem which PHP points out to you here. It's not a problem of PHP being inflexible, it's a problem of you making a logical faux pas and not seeing it. You'd have to redefine inheritance in its entirety to solve this problem.

Comment: @egig Two interfaces, each containing the same function definition, is perfectly valid. Can you post what you tried that didn't work? Type hinting makes interfaces inflexible, but that's its exact purpose - to make PHP complain if you try to give a method something it isn't expecting.