# Type hint for descendant classes

Tags: php, type-hinting

From the docs page http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children or implementations are allowed too.

But:

```
class PimpleChild extends Pimple {
//...
}
interface Pimple_Config {
    public function configure(Pimple $container);
}
class PimpleConfigurer_Factories implements Pimple_Config {
    public function configure(PimpleChild $container) {
    //...
    }
}
```

returns fatal error. Why?

Comment: Because you cannot change the signature of an implemented interface. Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567020/php-type-hinting-not-getting-along-with-interfaces-and-abstract-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I am not mistaken you get this error:

```
Declaration of PimpleConfigurer_Factories::configure() must be compatible with Pimple_Config::configure(Pimple $container) ...
```

Which means: If you define a method in a super class or in an interface, all sub classes (or classes implementing the interface) must use exactly this definition. You cannot use another type here.

**As for your quote from the documentation:**

> If class or interface is specified as type hint then all its children or implementations are allowed too.

This only means that you can pass a variable which is of a certain type or all its children.

For example: Say you have the following classes:

```
class Car {
    protected $hp = 50;
    public function getHp() { return $this->hp; }
}

class SuperCar extends Car {
    protected $hp = 700;
}
```

And a function (or method, no difference there) with type hint:

```
function showHorsePower(Car $car) {
    echo $car->getHp();
}
```

You can now pass all objects of type Car and all its sub classes (here SuperCar) to this function, like:

```
showHorsePower(new Car());
showHorsePower(new SuperCar());
```

Answer (score 3):

From the same [typehinting section you linked to](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php#language.oop5.interfaces.implements):

> The class implementing the interface must use the exact same method signatures as are defined in the interface. Not doing so will result in a fatal error.

For the method signatures to be the same, they must contain the exact same typehints. And also relevant because it is similar...

From the OOP [Basics - `extends`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.extends) section of the manual:

> When overriding methods, the parameter signature should remain the same or PHP will generate an `E_STRICT` level error. This does not apply to the constructor, which allows overriding with different parameters.