# PHP class implements interface where methods type hint interface getting compatibility errors

Tags: php, oop

I am getting an error that to me is weird, but maybe I am doing something wrong or have a misunderstanding of how these work. I tried Googling and looking at similar questions, but none of them seemed to be the same, so that's where I'm at now.

An overview: I have a model as a service, that implements `QueryableServiceProvider`. `QueryableServiceProvider` is an interface that has a method `single()` that type hints a `QueryStruct` interface as the parameter. Then back in my model as a service, I have a `single()` method that type hints the `SingleStruct` class. The `SingleStruct` class implements the `QueryStruct` interface. However, when I try and run this I am getting the error:

> Declaration of ModelServiceProvider::single(SingleStruct
>   $parameters): Model must be compatible with
>   QueryableServiceProvider::single(QueryStruct $parameters) in
>   ModelServiceProvider.php

So now for some code, which is going to be a little confusing because there are 5 different classes:

QueryableServiceProvider.php

```
interface QueryableServiceProvider {
    public function single(QueryStruct $parameters);
}
```

QueryStruct.php

```
interface QueryStruct {
    /** Stuff Here **/
}
```

SingleStruct.php

```
class SingleStruct implements QueryStruct {
    /** Stuff Here **/
}
```

Model.php

```
class Model {
    /** Model bits here **/
}
```

ModelServiceProvider.php

```
class ModelServiceProvider implements QueryableServiceProvider {
    public function single(SingleStruct $parameters): Model { // This is the line the error references
        /** Does the query and returns an instance of Model **/
    }
}
```

I am using PHP 7.1, just for clarification. I know this works when it's not interfaces like this, but I don't see why this should work so maybe someone can help me out. Hopefully there is enough information here to actually be able to help me haha.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well, according to this, [Php type hinting not getting along with interfaces and abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567020/php-type-hinting-not-getting-along-with-interfaces-and-abstract-classes)

PHP intentionally does this. I don't really see why, since you can normally type hint interfaces and it seems like as long as you as a programmer were using the interfaces properly (i.e. requiring what you're using) then logically it'd be fine.

But, I guess it's intentional to work this way so I'll just change my code :/ Bummer, seems less descriptive to me, but that's alright.

Answer (score 0):

You've specified **return type** for `single` method of `ModelServiceProvider`, while it doesn't meet the similarity principle of method signature against `single` methods signature in `QueryableServiceProvider` interface.

`single`'s signature in `QueryableServiceProvider`:

```
public function single(QueryStruct $parameters);
```

`single`'s signature in `ModelServiceProvider`:

```
public function single(SingleStruct $parameters): Model {}
```

You should make those exactly same, either by specifying return type in the interface(like this):

```
interface QueryableServiceProvider {
  public function single(QueryStruct $parameters) : Model;
}

class ModelServiceProvider implements QueryableServiceProvider {
  public function single(SingleStruct $parameters): Model {
    //method body
  }
}
```

or omitting it in your class's method(this way):

```
interface QueryableServiceProvider {
  public function single(QueryStruct $parameters) : Model;
}

class ModelServiceProvider implements QueryableServiceProvider {
  public function single(SingleStruct $parameters): Model {
    //method body
  }
}
```

### Update:

With thanks to @Kenyon's notice on testing the result on applying the previous fix, The second fix to the problem is to **Maintain the *exact* same type hinting in parameter declaration between the interface & implementer class** [As stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567020/php-type-hinting-not-getting-along-with-interfaces-and-abstract-classes#answers), *while you can pass an argument to the class which needs to be only `instanceof` the parameter type.*

So this MUST work:

```
interface QueryableServiceProvider {
  public function single(QueryStruct $parameters) : Model;
}

class ModelServiceProvider implements QueryableServiceProvider {
  public function single(QueryStruct $parameters): Model {
    //method body
  }
}
```

Comment: It isn't the return type differences (I tried that first, and got the same error)

Comment: Also, just changed the parameter type hints fixed it & all works now

Comment: @Kenyon The answer for this case can be found here: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4567020/php-type-hinting-not-getting-along-with-interfaces-and-abstract-classes> but try to maintain similar return type for the sake of best practices in OO design.

Comment: I think the point of interfaces is to maintain consistency without being strictly typed to something. Which is also the point of inheritance in my opinion. And inheritance is a lot of why I find OO useful anyways