# Message: Return type of CI_Session_files_driver::open($save_path, $name) should either be compatible with

Tags: php, session, codeigniter-3

I got this error after install a new xampp version (php8). and clone my codeigniter project.

```
Message: Return type of CI_Session_files_driver::open($save_path, $name)
should either be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface::open(string $path, string $name):
bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice
```

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 132

Comment: Fix the same way with this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867615/php-class-implements-interface-where-methods-type-hint-interface-getting-compati

Comment: it is a codeigniter system code. I can not understand how to fix it.

Comment: In that case maybe update Codeigniter to latest version but if problem still exists, please [report a bug](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/issues).

Comment: it's seems like codeigniter3 incompatible with php8 . I downgrade to php 7. now it works fine.

Comment: Codeigniter has fixed this bug in release 3.1.12. See http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/changelog.html

Answer (score 76, accepted):

For anyone else that comes across this error, I also experienced it after upgrading to PHP 8.1. The only way I could find to "fix" it was by adding `#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]` before the `open`, `read`, `write`, `close`, `destroy` and `gc` functions in `/system/libraries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php`. For example:

```
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function open($save_path, $name)
{
...
```

Comment: This worked for me but after these changes session flash is not destroying after page refresh.

Comment: Appears to be fixed with CI 3.1.13 --> `composer update` fixed it for me

Comment: These are upcoming bad issue which will create many troubles because to switching form 7 to 8 with ci3

Answer (score 36):

I experienced this error after re installing XAMPP Server. I have fixed this issue by adding

`#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]`

for all methods (`open, read, write, close, destroy and gc`) in `Session_files_driver.php file`. The file can find in project folder `system/libaries/Session/drivers/Session_files_driver.php`

```
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function open($save_path, $name)
{
   ...
}

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function read($session_id)
{
  ...
}

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function write($session_id, $session_data)
{
  ...
}

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function close()
{
  ...
}

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function destroy($session_id)
{
  ...
}

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
public function gc($maxlifetime)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: This is working fine for me with php v 8.*

Comment: This worked for me but after these changes session flash is not destroying after page refresh.

Comment: Destroy session flash after displaying error message.

Comment: Anyone looking for the solution to `Sessions files not automatically deleting from /var/lib/php/sessions/` here is the solution. Thanks, @JoyalGeorge

Comment: I met this issue after upgrading php7->8 in xampp, this worked for me.

Comment: in my case adding this is not fixing the error