# Message: Return type of CI_Session_files_driver::open($save_path, $name) should either be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface:

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am unable to find the solution for this error met in code igniter. I have tried every solutions available like drivers/Session_files_driver.php thats to apply in this page .

This is the error I am getting while logging to login page.***Message: Return type of CI_Session_files_driver::open($save_path, $name) should either be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface::open(string $path, string $name): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice***

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php

Line Number: 132

*Message: Return type of CI_Session_files_driver::close() should either be compatible with SessionHandlerInterface::close(): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice
Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php*
I have tried this solution [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508122/message-return-type-of-ci-session-files-driveropensave-path-name-should)

I have tried this solution [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70508122/message-return-type-of-ci-session-files-driveropensave-path-name-should)
**controller login.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Login extends CI_Controller {
       public function __construct()
      {
        parent::__construct();
        // $this->load->model('Login_Model');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        // $this->load->library('session');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->database();

      }
      public function index() { die("22");
$this->load->view('login');
}

// Validate and store registration data in database
 public function validate() { die("22");
  $this->load->helper('url');
if($this->input->post('username'))
{
  $this->db->where('username',$this->input->post('username'));
   $this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
   $rows=$this->db->get('login');
    if($rows->num_rows()==1)
    {
      $data = array('username'=>$this->input->post('username'),'is_logged_in'=>TRUE);
      $this->session->set_userdata('ci_session',$data);

      redirect('Motherindia/index');
          }
      }
      else{
        echo "<script>alert('Your password and username is wrong!Try again...!333');</script>";

    }
     $this->index();
  }
  public function logout()
  {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('ci_session');
     $this->load->view('login');
  }
}
```

Comment: Solution is:


#[AllowDynamicProperties] is to add before class

Example:
#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class CI_Loader {



#[\ReturnTypeWillChange] is to add before function

Example:
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
function myfunction{

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this one i had missed `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/miirps';`   in which `http://` in my config.php file

Answer (score 0):

#[AllowDynamicProperties] is to add before class

Example:
#[AllowDynamicProperties]
class CI_Loader {

#[\ReturnTypeWillChange] is to add before function

Example:
#[\ReturnTypeWillChange]
function myfunction{

this is resolve issue in PHP 8.2